# Найти и определить последовательности в массиве <int> данных

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Program
    {
        internal static void Calculate(int[] arr)
        {
            List<string> combinations = new List<string>();
            int countofcombinations = 1;
            string tempstr = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i - 1] < arr[i] && arr[i - 1] != arr[i])
                {
                    tempstr += arr[i - 1].ToString() + ",";
                }
                else if (arr[i - 1] != arr[i])
                {
                    combinations.Add(tempstr);
                    tempstr = "";
                    countofcombinations++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Input data: " + String.Join(",", arr));
            Console.WriteLine("Count of combinations: " + countofcombinations);
            Console.WriteLine("Combinations: " + String.Join(" | ", combinations));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculate(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 75, 4, 5, 6, 75, 7, 8, 9, 108, 1,2,3, 875 });
        }
    }
```

Выводит:

```
Input data: 1,2,3,75,4,5,6,75,7,8,9,108,1,2,3,875
Count of combinations: 4
Combinations: 1,2,3, | 4,5,6, | 7,8,9,         @(1,2,3)" - теряется
```

Но почему-то не выводит последнюю последовательность. В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

После окончания цикла `for` в `tempstr` теоретически может остаться (и точно остаётся в вашем случае) не обработанная строка. Нужно её обработать:

```
for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    // ...
}
if (tempstr.Length > 0)
{
    combinations.Add(tempstr);
    countofcombinations++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам уже ответили, почему метод не работает так как вы ожидаете.

Я же хочу показать пример хорошего кода:

```
public class Program
{
    public static List<List<int>> FindCombinations(int[] array)
    {
        if (array == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        
        var combinations = new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>() };
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
            {
                combinations.Add(new List<int>());              
                continue;
            }
            
            combinations.Last().Add(array[i]);
        }
        
        return combinations;
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inputArray   = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 75, 4, 5, 6, 75, 7, 8, 9, 108, 1, 2, 3, 875 };
        var combinations = FindCombinations(inputArray);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Input data: " + string.Join(", ", inputArray));
        Console.WriteLine("Count of combinations: " + combinations.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Combinations:");
        combinations.ForEach(combination => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", combination)));
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Input data: 1, 2, 3, 75, 4, 5, 6, 75, 7, 8, 9, 108, 1, 2, 3, 875
Count of combinations: 4
Combinations:
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3
```